# Pygame not downloading on mac

Tags: python, pip, pygame

When I use
`pip3 install pygame`
on my built in mac terminal, I expect it to return nothing or maybe something confirming the download, but instead I get

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/80/ct2vlpb17tq6fv7tk7fzrq300000gn/T/pip-install-0lflyyj6/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/80/ct2vlpb17tq6fv7tk7fzrq300000gn/T/pip-install-0lflyyj6/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/80/ct2vlpb17tq6fv7tk7fzrq300000gn/T/pip-record-riycfu31/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.`

That was only the error message itself, the actual output was about 400 lines long, I can post that if need be.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/macintosh#Current%20Instructions

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame` 1.9.6](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/1.9.6/#files) doesn't provide binary wheels for Python 3.8 for MacOS X; they provides wheels for w32/w64 and they provide wheels for MacOS X for Python 3.4-3.7.

My advice is to use Python 3.7. Python 3.8 is ok but 3rd-party modules are not yet available.